# Sharing HTML5 localstorage among multiple UIWebViews

Tags: ios, iphone, html, uiwebview

I have a ViewController which has multiple `UIWebViews`. I am using `localstorage.setItem` to store some variables. But the problem is that these variables are accessible only within the `UIWebViews` in which has been set. If i am trying to get( localstorage.getitem)  the variable of other `UIWebViews` it's giving null value .

WebView1=====>>>>`localStorage.setItem("var1","val");`

WebView2=====>>>>`alert(localstorage.getItem("var1"));`  ===>>is null

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but that's just how the framework is designed: every `UIWebView` is it's own instance, isolated from other instances in the same app (just like there is no built-in pop-up or tab functionality).

If there is absolute no other way around it, you could make the web views [Cordova WebView](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html#iOS%20WebViews)'s and programatically arrange for some way to transfer data between them via the native layer (there's also alternatives, like [WebViewJavascriptBridge](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge) that accomplishes the same thing).

Maybe you could even get by just by injecting the data needed using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` into a known data structure beforehand. But having the Javascript in a `UIWebView` call the native side is a well known difficult-to-do thing that can only be solved by using bridging solutions like i mentioned in the second paragraph.

Comment: However i have seen a strange behaviour . If you put alert in one `UIWebView` it's appearing in other .

Comment: How can you determine which view the alerts come from?

Comment: just put different messages in the alert of different `UIWebViews` to identify it

Comment: Of course, worded my question wrong: can you really see were it appears _over_ (it's `window.alert()` we are talking about, right)?